# How to get array length for array of strings

Tags: arrays, c, strlen

I want to find the number of elements in that array, but as far as I know I'm not allowed to use strlen or sizeof. strlen(array[0]) gives out 5 cause apple consists of 5 characters, but I need length to equal to 4, because the arrays contains 4 words. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char array[10][100] = {"apple", "banana", "strawberry", "grapefruit"};
    int length = strlen(array[0]);
    printf("%d", length);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Iterate over the words until you hit a word with zero length (or you hit the end of the array). To avoid the need for strlen, simply test the first character of each word (0 => empty string).

Comment: `char array[10][100];` has 10 elements.  Those elements are arrays of 100 char.  If you decide to initialize only 4 of them, then the number of initialized elements if 4 but the size is still 10.  You don't need strlen or size; you initialized 4 of them so 4 of them are initialized.  And the size remains 10.  Don't compute anything at run time; this is entirely knowable at compile time, and doing any computation at runtime is wasted cycles.  "As far as I know I'm not allowed to use ... sizeof".  Well, that's just silly, since sizeof is the right operator if you don't want to hard-code 4 or 10

Comment: @WilliamPursell... <pedantic>all 10 elements are initialized, there is no partial initialization in C</pedantic>

Comment: Why did you write 10 if you needed 4?

Comment: @pmg A valid point.  6 of the 10 elements are initialized to be all zero.  I still don't understand the point of this question!

Comment: @Wyck its just a part of a bigger project, I wanna add more strings

Comment: Then you should write something that is resistant to code maintenance (such as adding, removing or changing strings).  e.g. `const char* array[] = {"apple", "banana", "strawberry", "grapefruit"}` and use `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])` as an expression for the number of elements in the array.  Don't write unrelated `10` and `100` values into your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search over `array[i]` until you find an empty string:

```c
size_t arrayLength = 0;
for (size_t i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  if (array[i][0] != '\0')
  {
    arrayLength++;
  }
  else
  {
    // with brace initialization, there will be no other words in the
    // array, we're safe to break
    break;
  }
}
```

When you use a brace-initialization list like that with a specified size, it will initialize the array to the contents you provided, and 0 for everything else.  The *pointers* in the first dimension will still be valid (ie, `array[i]` is not-NULL for all `i` [0, 10) ), but they point to empty strings.

[Demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/qYv4q9ETd)

Comment: ITYM `if (array[i][0])` to check for empty string rather than NULL pointer. ... https://ideone.com/8Yf72w

Comment: @pmg Absolutely correct. In fact my last answer was completely wrong,, the first dimension of pointers are valid for each `array[i]`, but after the 4th word they don't point to anything. Whoops.

Comment: They decay to point to the empty strings, just as with the assigned elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the size of the array, the "correct" operator to use is `sizeof`.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int 
main(void)
{
    char array[][100] = {"apple", "banana", "strawberry", "grapefruit"};
    printf("%zd\n", sizeof array / sizeof *array);

    return 0;
}
```

I suspect the real issue here is that the `char array[10][100]` ought to be replaced with `char array[][100]`.  There is no need to do any run-time computation here.